# Jasper Reports datasource for JSON data

Tags: json, jasper-reports, ireport

Anyone know of an open source Jasper Reports DataSource implementation that can handle JSON data?  I'd like to utilize JSON data from a RESTful API in some custom reports. Before I build it myself, I figured I'd check if something already exists.

Comment: Tauren, how did you go with this? Did you find anything or write it yourself?

Comment: @Mark - I didn't find a solution or write one yet. Had more pressing things to do. I'm still not sure how to really go about doing this for a report running within iReport. But if you integrate reports into an application, then you could use JRBeanCollectionDataSource to create a datasource from POJOs you retrieve from a REST API. At least that's what I'm doing with data I pull from Hibernate.

Comment: This post will help you to get some ideas. http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/pdf-doc-xls-odf-from-php Thank you. Ajith Vitharana.

Answer (score 6):

There is a JSON Datasource in Jasper 5.0.1.  I think it is new with V5.

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JsonDataSource.html

The API doesn't tell you much.   Haven't found documentation for it yet.   The JasperReports Ultimate Guide I just downloaded (dated 1/15/2013) doesn't seem to have been updated with it.

I suspect it works somewhat like the XML Datasource:  you use paths (XPATH in the case of XML) to specify the fields.

Answer (score -1):

there is a sample of JsonDataSource in the 4.5.0 version of jasperreports at *\demo\samples\jsondatasource*