# parse to json object from a json url in jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a request that is add currency rates to the Jasper report. not only just latest rate, but also need historically rates. I found a json URL from Open Exchange Rates

my question is how to make data display in the Jasper report. Jasper write by JAVA, three are any API or template I can use?  first step must be parse url to json object and then loop json to make it display, that's what I thinking. if anyone can help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after research I found that can use scriptlets in jasper.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a JSON data source. The following thread would probably be a good start: [Jasper Reports datasource for JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269891/jasper-reports-datasource-for-json-data)